# Format function truncated after adding to regexp

Tags: python

### Issue

I'm working on a selenium tool and I need to wait on a page to update with today's date and time. Since I only need to verify if my element contains the abbreviated month and day of today, formatted as 'Oct 16', I added a custom EC to allow a regex search of my page's text. An example of what I'm searching is below:

- Ex. 1: Tue Oct 15 13:39:33 CDT 2019
- Ex. 2: Wed Oct 16 11:27:48 CDT 2019

The page initially contains an old date. A js function is triggered to update that date, which I need to wait on before moving on.

The problem is that my code seems to truncate the formatted day when using .format() and adding it to my regex.

1. `date.today()` returns the expected '2019-10-16'
2. `today.strftime('%b %d')` returns the expected 'Oct 16'
3. `"^(.*?(\b{}\b)[^$]*)$".format(day)` returns `'^(.*?Oct 1)[^$]*)$'`

**That is unexpected, and I'm not certain why that is taking place**. I'm using VS Code with an Anaconda install of python 3.6.

### Troubleshooting

I did confirm that my regex will work using https://www.regextester.com/98103
I simply inserted my regex, including my manual format of the date, and included an example text from my web page. This doesn't rule out the issue being here, as my understanding is that regex is not universal.

I attempted to drop the variables and format with the base code:
`date_regex = "^(.*?(\b{}\b)[^$]*)$".format(date.today().strftime('%b %d'))`

Attempting to just search for the day of 'Wed' using `.strftime('%a')` also appears to truncate to `'^(.*?We)[^$]*)$'` (and isn't ideal, as I could be a week old or more and fail to wait).

```py
from datetime import date
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

# custom expected condition
class wait_for_text_to_match(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, regexp):
        self.locator = locator
        self.regexp = regexp

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text
        return re.search(self.regexp, element_text)

# Code snip
                    today = date.today()
                    print(today) # Output: 2019-10-16
                    day = today.strftime('%b %d') # Ex: Oct 14
                    print(day) # output: Oct 16
                    date_regex = "^(.*?(\b{}\b)[^$]*)$".format(day)
                    date_regex
                    print(date_regex) # Output: ^(.*?Oct 1)[^$]*)$

                    wait.until(wait_for_text_to_match(
                        (By.XPATH, 
                        '//*[@id="syncInfo"]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]'), 
                        date_regex))
```

### Outcome Desired

My expectation is that the regex would be formatted to include the entire day I constructed.

- Current: `^(.*?Oct 1)[^$]*)$`
- Expected: `^(.*?Oct 16)[^$]*)$`

If done correctly, this would then be inserted into my custom EC and if found, cause my code to wait the defined timeout.

Comment: Is any of the posted code relevant except from `today = date.today()` through `print(date_regex)`?

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://ideone.com/HCVsJG

Comment: date_regex.replace("\x08", "") gives me '^(.*?(Oct 24)[^$]*)$' for today's date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a raw string for the regexp, or escape the backslashes. `\b` in a regular string literal is backspace, so when you print the regexp on the terminal it's backing up and printing the next character over the last digit of the date. And the regexp doesn't match because there's no backspace in the web page.

```
date_regex = r"^(.*?(\b{}\b)[^$]*)$".format(day)
```